# malloc in c, struct

Tags: c, struct, malloc

I made a struct like this:

```
struct a{
  char *name;
  char *value;
  struct a *next;
};
```

when I malloc for memory at first time, it's ok, and I can set 'name' and 'value' a corresponding value.
but when I malloc for the second time, errors come. And It's a cgi, just show me "500 Internal server error".

I changed the pointer 'name' and 'value' to array, everything works.

I thought maybe the complier doesn't know how much memory to assign.

And do you have some ideas with this? I will appreciate every answer!

Comment: You'll have to show more code -- were you storing directly into the values `a->name` or `a->value` or did you allocate memory for _them_, too?

Comment: I store values directly without allocate memory. And as Keith Thompson commented, I allocate memory for a->name and a->value, it works. Do you know the difference? thank you!

Answer (score 3):

```
struct a {
    char *name;
    char *value;
    struct a *next;
};

struct a *head = malloc(sizeof *head);
```

The above allocates space for a single `struct a` object, but it doesn't initialize any of hte three pointers contained in a `struct a`.  In particular, if you want `name` and `value` to point to strings, you'll need to allocate space for those strings:

```
head->name = malloc(5);
strcpy(head->name, "Fred");
head->value = malloc(8);
strcpy(head->value, "abcdefg";
```

This is considerably oversimplified.  `5` and `8` are "magic numbers"; you should specify the sizes in a way that will remain consistent if you change the initial values.  And you should *always* check whether `malloc()` returns a null pointer (even if you just terminate the program with an error message).

If you don't initialize `name` and `value` to point to some chunk of allocated memory, you *might* still be able to initialize what they point to (e.g., by doing the `strcpy`s above without the `malloc`s).  More precisely, the system won't necessarily diagnose the error.

Finally, you'll need a call to `free()` corresponding to each `malloc()` call.

Note that this is largely a guess based on your description.  If you can show us your actual code, we can help you better.

Comment: yeah, you are right. I just tested your method. It works. But one more question, when you use `head->name=malloc(5)`, you must know the size you want to malloc. so the process is : cacluate the length, then malloc. but I dont think it's efficiency. thank you again!

Comment: How you calculate the length depends on where the data is coming from.  If you have a `char*` pointer called `name` that points to the string you want to use as the name, you can do `head->name = malloc(strlen(name) + 1); if (head->name == NULL) { /* handle allocation failure */ } strcpy(head->name, name);`.  For example.  (The `+ 1` is necessary to hold the `'\0'` null character that terminates the string.)

Comment: here I want to parse the qeury string like "search=stackoverflow&keyword=malloc&language=en&else=null". so I can't find a efficiency way to do this.

Answer (score 2):

If you use `malloc` with `sizeof(struct a)` it's just going to assign enough space to store the pointers name and value. You want these to be char arrays, then it'll know how much space to set aside for each instance of `a`.

Comment: thank you, LaceySnr. you get a better understanding than me. It becomes clear to me.